# kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: kafka produce error

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am reading a json file and trying to produce it using kafka..
Here is my code:

```
public class FlatFileDataProducer {

    private String topic = "JsonTopic";
    private Producer<String, String> producer = null;
    KeyedMessage<String, String> message = null;
    public JsonReader reader;

    public void run(String jsonPath) throws ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException{
        reader = new JsonReader();
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        System.out.println("JSON FILE PATH IS : "+jsonPath);
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("metadata.broker.list", "192.168.63.145:9092");
        prop.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        // prop.put("partitioner.class", "example.producer.SimplePartitioner");
        prop.put("request.required.acks", "1");


        ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(prop);
        producer = new Producer<String, String>(config);
        List<Employee> emp = reader.readJsonFile(jsonPath);     
        for (Employee employee : emp) 
        {
            System.out.println("---------------------");
            System.out.println(employee.toString());
            System.out.println("---------------------");
            message = new KeyedMessage<String, String>(topic, employee.toString());

            producer.send(message);
            producer.close();

        }
         System.out.println("Messages to Kafka successfully");
    }
```

And code to read json file is:

```
public List<Employee> readJsonFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException{
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        parser=new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(path));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        employee.setId(Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.get("id").toString()));      
        employee.setName((String)jsonObject.get("name"));
        employee.setSalary(Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.get("salary").toString()));
        list.add(employee);
        return list;
    }
```

But when I execute the program,
**ISSUE 1:**

```
> [root@sandbox ~]# java -jar sparkkafka.jar /root/customer.json
> JSON FILE PATH IS : /root/customer.json
>  log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties). log4j:WARN Please
> initialize the log4j system properly.
> 1,Smith,25
> Exception in thread "main" kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send messages
> after 3 tries.
>         at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:91)
>         at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77)
>         at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
>         at com.up.jsonType.FlatFileDataProducer.run(FlatFileDataProducer.java:41)
>         at com.up.jsonType.FlatFileDataProducer.main(FlatFileDataProducer.java:49)
```

It gives error but when I check cosumer shell, I get like below: FOR ONE ROW IN JSON FILE I SEE 4 entry in shell.. 
**ISSUE 2:**

[root@sandbox bin]#
[root@sandbox bin]# ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic JsonTopic --from-beginning

```
1,Smith,25
1,Smith,25
1,Smith,25
1,Smith,25
```

I am getting 4 times the row for same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove both the below proprty:

```
    //prop.put("request.required.acks", "1");
    //prop.put("producer.type","async");
```

This property will actully takes care about acknowledgement.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding below property:

```
prop.put("producer.type","async");
```